How to sample random spanning trees according to probability
Suppose I have an undirected, weighted graph $G$, where the weight of each edge $e$, denoted $w(e)$, is a value such that $0 < w(e) < 1$. I treat the edge weights as probabilities of inclusion, and assume the edges are independent. I am interested in the probability distribution over all subgraphs $H \subseteq G$, which is given by:
$$
P(H) = \prod_{e \in E(H)} w(e) \prod_{e \in E(G) \setminus E(H)} (1 - w(e)).
$$
Is there a way to sample spanning trees of $G$ according to the probability $P(T \mid T \text{ is a spanning tree of } G)$?
I have already conducted some research and found a few related results (e.g., Wilson’s Algorithm). However, most similar algorithms sample spanning trees proportional to the weight of the edges, rather than the probability distribution described above. Specifically, they sample spanning trees such that:
$$
P(T) \propto \prod_{e \in E(T)} w(e).
$$
Alternatively, what general techniques could I use to sample spanning trees from this distribution if no exact algorithm exists?

The two probability distributions you describe are equivalent, just with different weights. Specifically, your first formula can be written as $$P(H) = \prod_{e \in E(H)} \frac{w(e)}{1-w(e)} \prod_{e \in E(G)} (1 - w(e))$$ which means $$P(H) \propto \prod_{e\in E(H)} \frac{w(e)}{1-w(e)},$$ which is like giving edge $e$ the weight $\frac{w(e)}{1-w(e)}$ and then using the second formula.

Ok yeah I see where you're going with that! I'm using this spanning tree sampling technique in some code so I'll try modifying the edge weights tomorrow my time and see if that fixes my problem.

The comment made by Misha is indeed correct, constructing a graph $G^\prime$ with weights $w^\prime(e) = \frac{w(e)}{1 - w(e)}$ and sampling spanning trees from $G^\prime$ according to weight is equivalent to sampling spanning trees of $G$ according to probability.
